# How will you post and get data using one single call in Angular?

Tags: angular, http

I just had an interview and the interviewer asked me - Suppose I make a post call in angular using HTTP and I get a response 200 OK. This means that a new Id is generated. Now I will have to make a separate GET call to get this Id. Is there a way possible to get this id in one single call ?

I said depends on the server response.If the response has the Id we can simply subscribe to the observable and get its value. He said no we are only getting the OK response. I couldn't think of any other way. Then he said Have you heard of promises in angular ? I don't know how will I achieve this in single call using a promise.

This is how I know how to use promises in Angular for a POST call :

```
@Injectable()
export class WebApiPromiseService {
    headers: Headers;
    options: RequestOptions;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                                     'Accept': 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9' });
        this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    }

    createService(url: string, param: any): Promise<any> {
    let body = JSON.stringify(param);
    return this.http
        .post(url, body, this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }  

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not return the Id in the first response ? I think this is the only way to to do it in single request.

Comment: I really would love to talk to this interviewer. The only way that comes to mind is to generate id on the front-end (uuid) and send it in the post request and when we get 200 OK it just meas that the id that we generated is in the db. And I'm not sure how promises relate to that, since the correct way to call backend in angular is via httpclient and with the use of observables.

Comment: If response is only OK you need to have 2 calls

Comment: I told him the same thing that we need to make either two calls or respond with the request id itself from the server. Do let me know If you guys find any other solution.

Comment: i think it depends on what this guy meant ... if he means one single call based on one function in angular .. yeah, that is possible, but in the end it would be 2 server requests anyway.

Comment: @djnose - I know we can make two http calls in a function. When he mentioned Promise I did say that we can make another call but he said very clearly you can't make two http calls. I hope I never get this question again in an interview.

Comment: @PrateekChitransh maybe he wanted to hear something like Promise.all(....) .. no idea :) you should have asked him what exactly his solution is...